# Get serviceaccount info according to its corresponding token in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, token

In kubernetes, every serviceaccount has a corresponding secret which hold a token.How can I get the serviceaccount' Info(ex. name and namespace) through the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SA secret token is based on JWT
you can use for example: https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ to get a json containing the information of the token as follow:

```
{
 "iss": "kubernetes/serviceaccount",
 "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace": "**<your_namespace>**",
 "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/secret.name": "**<your_sa_name>-token-xxxxx**",
 "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.name": "**<your_sa_name>**",
 "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.uid": "**<your_sa_uid>**",
 "sub": "system:serviceaccount:<your_namespace>:**<your_sa_name>**",
 "jti": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 "iat": 9999999999,
 "exp": 9999999999
}
```

Hope this helps